# Take a numpy array of x points and reshape it into an array of y points

Tags: numpy, padding

I have a numpy array of a certain number of points. I wish to take this array and change the number of points using padding and interpolation, but have the array look the same when plotted on something like MatPlotLib.

I have tried out functions such as `np.repeat`, `np.kron`, `np.lib.pad` with little success.

eg)

`lista = [1,2,3,4,5]` contains 5 points

I would like this to be reshaped to be 10 points

`listb = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.4,4,4.5,5,5.5]` contains 10 points but still looks the same when plotted

Comment: those are only 9 points in your output...

Comment: Do you just want a linear interpretation between points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a linear function fit a linear function to it and evaluate it on the wanted values:

```
import numpy as np
x_axis = np.arange(5) # These are your x-values for plotting with matplotlib
lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So now fit a linear polynom:

```
linear_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x_axis, lista, 1))
```

and evaluate it on the same grid but with more steps:

```
linear_fit(np.linspace(x_axis[0], x_axis[-1], 9))
# array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ])
```

when plotting make sure you use the new x-grid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
new_x = np.linspace(x_axis[0], x_axis[-1], 9)
plt.scatter(new_x, linear_fit(new_x), color='b')
plt.plot(x_axis, lista, color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d
then try out the different spline `kinds`. If your data are not very smooth, higher order splines can generate undesirable swings, since they try to connect the data with smooth curves (1st or even 2nd order derivatives are matched).